# Drag-and-Drop With Lotus Notes Keeping Subject as Filename

Tags: lotus-notes

I have multiple emails in Lotus Notes that I want to keep copies as .eml files.

I have been using drag-and-drop, and noticed that the subject like is getting truncated.

Is there a way to copy multiple files from lotus notes using drag-and-drop and keep the full subject as the filename?

Comment: This is not a programming question, it belongs on Super User, not Stack Overflow, IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Subject might contain bad characters that DOS wouldn't allow.  ( Eg. ? / : to name a few.)  So, keeping the full subject as the filename won't be 100% possible.

1) The Notes 9 client solves the problem.

2) If you cannot upgrade, then manually copy and paste the Subject into the file name of the Files Save-As dialogue box and remove the bad characters.